# Is it possible to use a .Net GUI in a Java project?

Tags: c#, java, user-interface

As a beginner programmer, I want to ask is there any way to using .Net (preferably C#) GUI in java project? That is because i feel C# can design GUI better and easier than Java, but as i heard, J2EE is more powerful than C# (no source, correct me if I wrong).

So, is it possible? Running C# UI in java?

Comment: (1) Whatever you do in C#/VB.NET/C++\CLI or any CLS compliant language can be used regardless of the language it was built with in the .NET context.  (2) If this were possible you are doing it for the wrong reasons.

Comment: I think C# has more language features and therefore is more powerful than java

Comment: @JonathonReinhart: you're arguing how many angels can dance on the head of a pin here. "more powerful" has no meaning without reference to a specific metric.

Comment: To the original poster: Since you're a beginner I suggest that you just concentrate on learning a language and learning it well. No need to over complicate things by trying to meld together that which is difficult to do. At this stage whether you choose to learn Java or C# isn't as important as how well you learn it.

Comment: .NET is younger then Java but grows faster. C# has many powerful features. It's more trendy. Have better support. I vote for C# and .NET

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- C# has no UI. .Net has (Winforms, Silverlight, WPF, ASP.Net...)
- Running Winforms/Silverlight/WPF... from Java code isn't possible.
- C# is a programming language, J2EE isn't. You can't compare them.
- I don't think Microsoft eco-system (.Net, C#, Entity Framework, Silverlight...etc.) is less powerful than J2EE in any way.

Answer (score 5):

If you're going to use WinForms, the theoretical advantage you might get from writing part of your project in Java is dwarved by the enourmous difficulties you're going to encounter when trying to integrate the two technologies.

And yes, as far as I know, no UI in Java comes near WinForms and WPF.

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not possible to "run" C# UI in Java.

But from your question maybe you are looking for a good GUI Designer tool for Java, if so take a look at [WindowBuilder](http://eclipse.org/windowbuilder/) eclipse plugin from google,it is even better of Visual Studio designer in my opinion ...

Answer (score 0):

1. Whatever you do in C#/VB.NET/C++\CLI or any CLS compliant language can be used regardless of the language it was built with in the .NET context.   C# is a language, .NET has libraries for doings thing like Windows apps, web apps etc.
2. If what you're asking were possible you are doing it for the wrong reasons. If you are using JAVA then you should use JAVA for your GUI development.

See https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=developing+gui+applications+java

Not a Java expert but you could take a look at Oracle ADF:
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/adf/overview/index.html

When writing windows applications on .NET, winforms and especially WPF is very powerful, (they come from the same guys who wrote windows), but it would be easier to just pick up Windows Programming with C#  than trying to use .NET GUI in your Java app.

Answer (score 0):

It may be possible to accomplish this by running your Java code in [IKVM.NET](http://www.ikvm.net/) (I've never done it though). If you're new to programming you should probably stick to learning one language at at time though.